# Can't get actual error in response for REST request. Fiddler shows me more error details. In .NET all I get is 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, rest, fiddler

In .NET, I am calling a rest service and getting an exception - `500 Internal Server Error`.

```
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse
```

When I analyze this in Fiddler (in TextView), I am getting many details about the proper exception that caused the error.

In my exception object, I can't get this information in the `InnerException` (it's null) nor in the `Response` object itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the fiddler results? Do you have access to the REST server at all?

Comment: Work on your answers :)  Please don't make assumptions, I accept answers that are correct.  Most of my questions go unanswered or not answered correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try looking at the [WebException.Response Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx):

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription);

        using (Stream responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(responseReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a dream.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The "inner" exception is happening on the remote host.  The [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) has a Response property which you can read to get the details.