# C# REST API: xml as post data

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I'm working on a project which requires me to work with an REST API. The API expects a DTO as input parameter.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "campaign/create?session={sessionkey}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
        FeedbackDTO PersistCampaign(string sessionkey, CampaignDTO PaycentoCampaign);
```

I'm trying to send the data to this method with the following method:

```
public static HttpWebResponse DoHttpWebRequest(String url, String method, string data)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.ContentType = "application/xml";
    req.Method = method;
    if ((method.Equals("POST") || method.Equals("PUT")) && data != null)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();
    }
    return req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

After hours of debugging I found that the problem is caused by the DateTime proprties. I started to 'manually' create the XML and do property per property.

```
 sb.Append("<Startdate>").Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Startdate.ToString(Helper.DATE_FORMAT_STRING))).Append("</Startdate>");
```

I tried adding a format (ddMMyyyy) in the toString but it's still causing a bad request. How should I add a DateTime property to the XML so ASP.NET is able to parse it into the DTO?

Stuff I tried:

- StartDate.ToLongDateString()
- StartDate.ToString()
- StartDate.toString("ddhhyyyy")
- StartDate.Ticks

Comment: @HenkHolterman It doesn't recognize the Service is a valid service.

Comment: Wrap GetResponse in a try and use the code in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948367/cant-get-actual-error-in-response-for-rest-request-fiddler-shows-me-more-error/9948511#9948511 to get the actual response from the server and post that too.

Comment: @JamieSee Added a the local variables in.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Can you exp[a,ou]nd on your question/suggestion? If I tried to guess what you mean by that, I would probably have to end up asking myself, "Are you sure Henk done it this way?"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - it's an old, heavily edited question but I'm not sure that an SVC proxy should work for a REST service. It's certainly not the best practicce (anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartdDate.toString("s") did the trick.